# why no parseInt for if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a = $('.box').width();

var b = $(document).height();
```

Now, let's say 124px, is an `int` or `string` ?

So far I have done this through trial and error, but now I'm curious to understand why `if (b < 20)`, however `parseInt` is needed to calculate `var c = a + b`. why is that?

Comment: Read this three times and I'm still not sure what the question is.

Comment: In my quick opinion the "<" is for math calculations where the "+" is also used for string concatenation. If you wish to "add" two numbers you need to use parseInt to make them integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't.

`.width()` and `height()` return numbers, not strings, and so don't need to be converted using `parseInt(...,10)`. I don't know who the "we" is you refer to, but it does not include people who use jQuery correctly.

Try it out on this very website - open up a console, and type `var d = jQuery("div"); console.log(typeof d.height(), typeof d.width(), d.height() + d.width());`, and you'll see [number], [number], and the result of a normal numeric addition.

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: I'm assuming that `a` and `b` are strings like `"10"` and `"20"`, for the purposes of this question. `$('.box').width()` will actually return `123` (if your element was 123 pixels wide, for example), so in this case `parseInt` is irrelevant.

---

Because in

```
a + b
```

If you don't use `parseInt`, then JavaScript will assume you want to concatenate the strings (because `+` is overloaded for concatenation). However, when you use

```
b < 20
```

JS knows that you can't have "a string less than 20," because that makes no sense, so it casts to a number automatically.

Comment: +1 for being able to understand terrible question

Comment: Please refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/V5mSd/4/ -- jQuery width() or height() methods return a number, not a string.

Comment: @DanyP As I noted at the top of my answer.

Comment: But in the question, he asks if it's int or string. a and b born return a number. Then he states the parseInt is required, which is flawed.

Comment: @DanyP Yes, and that is exactly what I noted at the top of my answer.

Comment: @Doorknob I think you must delete or edit this question because it seems they are int not string

Comment: @codinfreak Again, I mentioned that at the top of the answer (not question)

Comment: @codinfreak The point of Stack Overflow is to help future visitors. Someone who is searching for "parseint with if statements" may find this question and wonder why you need it if they are strings.

Comment: @codinfreak Please name one error in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37704/discussion-between-codin-freak-and-doorknob)

Answer (score 1):

because when you use the < operators it only makes sense for numbers to be bigger or smaller, however for the "+", in javascript it could be used to concatenate strings as well so:
"30"+"20"="3020"
and 30+20=50

NOTE: @Mike Poxman Kamerman is right, for the most part it will work without parseInt because the width and height jquery functions return floats but it is the correct practice as javascript used to be very strict and in browsers like older IEs it could not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing a string and a number, one has to be converted to the type of the other for the comparison to be possible. The string will implicitly be converted to a number.

When you are using the `+` operator with two strings, there is no conversion needed for the operation to be possible. It will just concatenate the strings, but if you want to use the operator for addition instead of concatenation, then you need to explicitly convert the strings to numbers first.